# Accessing redirected-to URL when making an HTTP request

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When making an HTTP request (using URLLoader, for example) that results in a redirect, is it possible to access any of the URLs in the redirect chain?

For example, let's say that the following happens:

1. We make a request to example.com/a.gif
2. example.com redirects to example2.com/b.gif
3. example2.com redirects to example3.com/c.gif

I've stared at the documentation for URLLoader and its various events for a while, and it doesn't seem like there's a way to either:

1. Instruct URLLoader to not follow redirects
2. Access any of the URLs involved after the initial request

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this? I'm not attached to using URLLoader, so if there's another class that supports this functionality, I'd be fine with using it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

**Edit** - I should clarify: I know how to detect the redirects outside of AS3 using a DOM debugger. I'm specifically interested in accessing the redirect chain within AS3. It would appear that it's possible using the AIR player via the [HttpStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html#responseURL), but the relevant properties aren't available when using Flash Player.

**Edit 2** - I've also tried using an HTTP client lib (as3httpclientlib, to be specific). This works except for the fact that it loads cross-domain policies from port 843 rather than by making an HTTP request to /crossdomain.xml. The context I'm working in requires the latter, so using something with Socket underlying it won't work unless there's a way to force Socket to load cross-domain policies from HTTP instead of port 843.

Comment: Are these server side redirects or client side redirects?  If they are server side; won't they be transparent to the Flex app?

Comment: They're server-side redirects (that's why I said "example.com" redirects to example2.com). The redirects are followed automatically. I'm trying to find a way to intercept the redirects, or at least be aware that they're happening.

Comment: You might have more success doing this with the [AS3HTTPClient library](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient). This library uses a Flash Socket to make HTTP requests ... as a result you should be able to get at the HTTP response and the result code that it contains. I'm assuming AS3HTTPClient follows redirects, but that you'll have to probably modify the source to make it dispatch events to notify you that it's following a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this as well, and it's capable of doing what I want. It won't quite do, however, because it uses Socket to do all of its network stuff, which loads loads cross-domain policies from port 843 of the remote host rather than from /crossdomain.xml. I didn't mention that this is a requirement, but it is. Do you know if there's a way to force it to load cross-domain policies over HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

The redirects are generally in place because the original URL shouldn't be used anymore.  The file doesn't exist at example.com/a.gif so in theory you don't need to know about it.  Why do you need the intermediate request path?

I'm not aware of an actionscript way of finding the redirect chain for any request, but if you want to do it for a specific chain you can use HttpFox for Firefox, or hit f12 in google chrome and look at the network tab when making a request to the URL that redirects.  This will only work if the client is redirected by the server to the new address (a HTTP 302 responce or similar.)  If the server chooses to return the contents of example3.com/c.gif when someone's browser asks for example.com/a.gif there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Sure, usually. Sometimes redirects are used for other reasons, however. For example, when you request an advertisement, there are normally many redirects before you're actually served the content. This is usually because many companies want to see the traffic, so they just redirect a user around before serving the content.

I know how to detect the redirects outside of AS3. I'm particularly interested in doing it in AS3.

Comment: hm.... this might be of use: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html)  in particular lookout for _Content-Location_ or set _Max-Forwards_

Comment: That's a request header. I'd need the response headers.

Comment: hm... how about adding an event handler on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus this looks like it would get fired once per responce instead of just when the call is fully resolved.

Comment: Right, I've tried this. It's only fired after all of the redirects have been followed, and only Adobe AIR (i.e., not Flash Player) has access to the responseURL / response headers. I edited my answer a bit ago to clarify that. Sorry I wasn't clearer.